# How to use spider.py python module

Tags: python, web-crawler

I've downloaded the spider.py 0.5 module from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spider.py/0.5). Inside the **spider.py** file there are lots of functions, one of them is:-

```
def webspider(self, b=None, w=200, d=5, t=None):

    '''Returns two lists of child URLs and paths
    b -- base web URL (default: None)
    w -- amount of resources to crawl (default: 200)
    d -- depth in hierarchy to crawl (default: 5)
    t -- number of threads (default: None)'''

    if b: self.weburls(b, w, d, t)
    return self.webpaths(), self.urls
```

I've created a new file in the same directory called **run.py** with the following code:-

```
import spider

webspider(b='http://example.com', w=200, d=5, t=5)
```

When i execute **run.py** i'm getting the following message:

```
NameError: name 'webspider' is not defined
```

Any ideas on how I can correctly use this module? I would like all links found to be saved into a file called **urls.txt**.

Comment: BTW, there is an indentation error in you first block. First line should be unindented.

Comment: Oh yes, let me edit that. In the original file all indentation is done correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call it like this:

```
import spider
spider.webspider(b='http://example.com', w=200, d=5, t=5)
```

Or you can only import `webspider`:

```
from spider import webspider
webspider(b='http://example.com', w=200, d=5, t=5)
```

You can rename imported method:

```
from spider import webspider as myspider
myspider(b='http://example.com', w=200, d=5, t=5)
```